# Insert Query Works On H2 but Not On Spring/Java itself

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I'm trying to develop a track rating web project with Spring Boot, on basic level.
I've written two seperate Entities that have Many to Many relationship with each other. Which are Tracks and Singers

After writing these classes, I have written two seperate Repository classes to test database queries with API Tester and H2 console. On each of those repositories, there is a method to link Track and Singer with a custom native SQL Query, since there's another database called "Track_Singers" is created after executing the entity classes' code.

On last note, I've additionally written two seperate methods in my service classes, to link tracks and singers between each other by using these repositories.

It gives me off some exception/errors on Java console and response code 500 when I'm trying to reach out from a Controller. And I must also mention that the query I've written in each of my repositories does work on H2 Console itself but not on these lines of code in java or during API Web Testing.

**Track.java**

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "Track")
public class Track {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private int ratedCount = 1;

    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    @Range(min = 0, max = 10)
    private double avgRating;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Track_Singers",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "track_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            }
    )
    private Set<Singer> singers;
}
```

**Singer.java**

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "Singer")
public class Singer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Track_Singers",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "singer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "track_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            }
    )
    private Set<Track> tracks;
}
```

**TrackRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface TrackRepository extends JpaRepository<Track, String> {



    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE TRACK " +
            "SET RATED_COUNT = RATED_COUNT + 1, " +
            "AVG_RATING = (RATED_COUNT / (RATED_COUNT + 1.0)) * AVG_RATING + (1.0 / (RATED_COUNT + 1.0)) * :newRating " +
            "WHERE ID = :id",
        nativeQuery = true)
    void updateRatingById(@Param("id") String id, @Param("newRating") double newRating);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) " +
            "SELECT s.ID, t.ID " +
            "FROM SINGER s" +
            "JOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = :singer_id AND t.ID = :track_id",
            nativeQuery = true)
    void addSingerToTrack(@Param("singer_id") Long singer_id, @Param("track_id") String track_id);
}
```

And lastly **SingerRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface SingerRepository extends JpaRepository<Singer, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) " +
            "SELECT s.ID, t.ID " +
            "FROM SINGER s" +
            "JOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = :singer_id AND t.ID = :track_id",
            nativeQuery = true)
    void addTrackToSinger(@Param("singer_id") Long singer_id, @Param("track_id") String track_id);
}
```

**linking methods on one of my service class**

```java
public Track addSingerForTrack(Long singer_id, String track_id)
{
        Track track = trackRepository.findById(track_id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Track not found"));
        Singer singer = singerRepository.findById(singer_id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Singer not found"));

        Set<Singer> singers = track.getSingers();

       
        if(
            !singers.stream()
                .map(Singer::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains(singer_id)
        ) {
            singers.add(singer);
        }

        track.setSingers(singers);
        trackRepository.save(track);
        trackRepository.addSingerToTrack(singer.getId(), track_id); // EXCEPTION IS THROWN IN HERE DURING API TESTING
        //return trackToDTO(track);
        return track;
    }

public Singer addTrackForSinger(Long singer_id, String track_id)
{
        Track track = trackRepository.findById(track_id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Track not found"));
        Singer singer = singerRepository.findById(singer_id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Singer not found"));

        Set<Track> tracks = singer.getTracks();

        if(
                !tracks.stream()
                        .map(Track::getId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()).contains(track_id)
        ) {
            tracks.add(track);
        }

        singer.setTracks(tracks);
        singerRepository.save(singer);
        singerRepository.addTrackToSinger(singer.getId(), track_id); // EXCEPTION IS THROWN IN HERE DURING API TESTING
        //return trackToDTO(track);
        return singer;
    }
```

**Bunch of ugly errors**

```
INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ? [42000-224]
2024-03-05T18:05:57.412+03:00 ERROR 23072 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement [Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN [*]TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ?"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ? [42000-224]] [INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ?]; SQL [INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ?]] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN [*]TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ?"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO TRACK_SINGERS (SINGER_ID , TRACK_ID) SELECT s.ID, t.ID FROM SINGER sJOIN TRACK t ON s.ID = ? AND t.ID = ? [42000-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:247) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.ParserBase.getSyntaxError(ParserBase.java:748) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:486) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:639) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:559) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1166) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:93) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:316) ~[h2-2.2.224.jar:2.2.224]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeNonSelectQueryPlanImpl.lambda$executeUpdate$0(NativeNonSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.StandardJdbcMutationExecutor.execute(StandardJdbcMutationExecutor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeNonSelectQueryPlanImpl.executeUpdate(NativeNonSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:835) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractQuery.java:650) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:266) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy137.addSingerToTrack(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at songrating.project.demo.services.TrackSingerService.addSingerForTrack(TrackSingerService.java:170) ~[classes/:na]
    at songrating.project.demo.controllers.TrackController.addSingerToTrack(TrackController.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:261) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:917) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:829) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:593) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
```

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between alias `s` and `JOIN`:

```java
"FROM SINGER s" +
            "JOIN
```

You need to add it.

Comment: This gives me a different error which includes a unique key violation. I think in console, it wants me to add a unique key to the Track_Singers table, but since this table is constructed via Many-to-Many relationship, it doesnt have any identifying keys.
`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_1 ON PUBLIC.TRACK_SINGERS(SINGER_ID, TRACK_ID) VALUES ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT),'11dFghVXANMlKmJXsNCbNl')"; SQL statement:`